# What happened to Angie and Archie in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

Clara was a nanny to to Archie and Arnie (perhaps two of the worst characters in Who-history) but they seemed to just disappear after a nightmare in Silver.

Is there an explanation of why they were just dropped?

Comment: Like most secondary characters, they were just quietly written out; http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Artie_Maitland

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They appear very briefly in "[The Name of the Doctor](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-14.htm)". The Doctor is baby-sitting them while Clara sleeps. They trick him into putting on a blindfold and bunk off down to the cinema, evidently having grown bored of having a friend who's a time-traveling alien. That is their last appearance and we're left to assume that they simply continued to live their lives as ordinary children.

---

As to *why* they were written out of the show, good luck finding anyone who's willing to go on record. It is however quite instructive to look at the critical reviews of their characters

[Steven Cooper](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WsTDBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT136&lpg=PT136&dq=%22angie%20and%20artie%22%20and%20review%20and%20brats&source=bl&ots=7ilw94KZU9&sig=84NiikyQFC-NHIblaBOK0ZxU0zc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAmoVChMIjYux-cu_xwIVQW8UCh1h8w7A#v=onepage&q=%22angie%20and%20artie%22%20and%20review%20and%20brats&f=false) described them as

> *struggling to rise above adequacy*

By [Radio Times](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2013-05-11/doctor-who-nightmare-in-silver-review-an-almighty-cyber-flop-id-never-willingly-sit-through-again) as

> *sullen and annoying*

and by [IGN](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2013/05/12/doctor-who-nightmare-in-silver-review) as

> *annoying, talentless and punchable*

Comment: Describing children as "punchable" not one of Snow's finer moments, it must be said.

Comment: I know your google-fu must be powerful but rhetorically... how do you find this stuff?

Comment: @kaine - I googled "angie and Artie" and "review" and then scanned through the top 20-30 pages looking for references

Comment: @Valorum Don't forget "brats", as can be seen in your [first link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WsTDBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT136&lpg=PT136&dq=%22angie%20and%20artie%22%20and%20review%20and%20brats&source=bl&ots=7ilw94KZU9&sig=84NiikyQFC-NHIblaBOK0ZxU0zc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAmoVChMIjYux-cu_xwIVQW8UCh1h8w7A#v=onepage&q=%22angie%20and%20artie%22%20and%20review%20and%20brats&f=false) :P

Answer (score 12):

The characters of Angie and Artie were only around to provide substance to Clara's day job as a nanny. We would see them whenever we saw Clara "at work", which meant she was in their house.

The last time we see either of them is in "Name of The Doctor", when they briefly appear at the beginning of the episode as part of the setup. The next time we see her, in the opening scene of "The Day of The Doctor", she now has another day job: she's an English teacher. Since she no longer babysits for the Maitland family, there's no reason for their children to appear in the show. Instead, we see more of Clara's own personal life, specifically her relationship with Danny Pink.

No reason is ever given on-screen for why she quit being a nanny, but presumably being a teacher is what she wanted to do, and her experiences with The Doctor must have convinced her to go for it.

---

Out-of-universe, everyone hated those kids; when the transition from Eleven to Twelve was being planned, it provided a good opportunity to write them out.

Comment: What was wrong with the kids?

Comment: as I understand it, the characters were not popular with fans, and they rarely had anything significant to do. They were also written as whiney, annoying, smart-ass kids too smart for their own good (who are completely unphased by time travel) that ruined the one episode the writers force-fit them into.